# Postgres: how to limit the number of query results by aggregate type

Tags: postgresql, query, aggregate

Consider the following table definition

```
CREATE TABLE associations (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    resource_id integer,
    target_id integer,
    relation_id integer
);
```

which is used for specifying the association of a resource to a target by means of a relation:

```
296 10  49  4 <--
297 10  50  4 <--
298 10  51  4 <--
299 10  52  4
300 10  53  4
301 10  54  4
302 10  55  4
303 10  56  5 <--
304 10  57  5 <--
305 10  58  7
306 10  59  7
307 10  60  7
308 10  61  7
309 10  62  7
310 10  64  8 <--
316 11  80  8 <--
320 11  81  8 <--
321 11  82  8 <--
322 11  83  8
```

- resource 10 is associated to targets [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55] by relation 4
- resource 10 is also associated to targets [56, 57] by relation 5

How can one query the **associations** table to get the targets of resources for specific relations (e.g. 4, 5 and 8) while **limiting the number of returned targets per relation**?

For example if we were to limit the number of targets to 3 on relations 4, 5 and 8 we should obtain the following result:

```
10 | 49, 50, 51 | 4
10 |     56, 57 | 5
10 |         64 | 8
11 | 80, 81, 82 | 8
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT resource_id, 
                target_id,
                relation_id, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY resource_id, relation_id 
                                    ORDER BY id ) rn
         FROM associations
         WHERE relation_id IN (4, 5, 8) )
SELECT resource_id, STRING_AGG(target_id::TEXT, ','::TEXT), relation_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY resource_id, relation_id
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fdeb0ff7c88dd75d7ab9b2ec99ef3aaa)

Comment: thank you for your help. Question: why do you use STRING_AGG(target_id::TEXT, ','::TEXT) ? I would think that ARRAY_AGG is more appropriate.

Comment: @slombo Your example output was not an array (no curly braces), so string_agg is what replicates your example.

Comment: @slombo If you need the array data type output in practice you may replace STRING_AGG with ARRAY_AGG freely.